# Drawing on uiimageview is resizes uiimage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I'm trying to add a drawing functionality using touch events on my `UIImage` (inside a `UIImageView`). However, for certain images, when I begin drawing, the image starts shrinking and becomes blurier the more i draw on it. I mostly used ray wenderlich's old drawing tutorial for reference, just changed values to match my UI. The two images show you what happens when i draw:

[image: Before drawing]

[image: After]

It looks like I'm using pretty standard methods for the drawing. My hunch is that the bounds/rectangle drawing methods are causing some sort of problem.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(_allowDoodling == NO) return;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self.imageView];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(_allowDoodling == NO) return;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imageView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imageView.frame.size, NO, 2.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [_imageView.image drawInRect:_imageView.bounds];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _doodleColor.CGColor);

    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    _imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(_allowDoodling == NO) return;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imageView.frame.size, NO, 2.0f);
    [_imageView.image drawInRect:_imageView.bounds];
    _imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It posible, that you have to use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(_imageView.frame.size.width * 2, _imageView.frame.size.width * 2), NO, 1.0f);
```